# Solve differential equation using substitution

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I need a hand in solving the following differential equation:

$$  {dR \over dt}  = \sqrt{{A\over R} + {\Gamma c^2 R^2\over 3}} $$

I think I need to use a substitution along the lines of $\cosh(u) $ equal to something under the square root but I'm not having much joy. Any help is appreciated

Comment: where is ''r'' on the right side?

Comment: Apologies, edited

Comment: Is your gamma function like this: $\Gamma\left(c^2\cdot R(t)^2\right)$, or is gamma a constant?

Comment: It's a constant

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $S=R^{3/2}$, then $$\frac{dS}{dt}=\frac32\sqrt{A+\frac{\Gamma c^2S^2}3}$$
Now do the standard sinh substitution